# Diference between jdk/bin/java and jdk/jre/bin/java

Tags: java, jvm

Making somes tests this week i found this situation:

When i run the tomcat using the java executable in jdk/jre/bin/java the performance is a lot betther than when i run with jdk/bin/java.
The question is: Someone knows why the jdk package delivers 2 java executables and what is the difference between them that justifies the performance difference?

Comment: Can you share the benchmark tests? There is no difference between them. JRE is runtime environment which is only need to run the program and not packed with extra utilities (jstack, jconsole, javah). Performance should not vary between the java.exe inside JDK bin to the one is JRE bin

Comment: Also, please share the Java version (java -version) for each. I'm assuming you're running the OpenJDK. Is there a difference in the file-size? You could have conflicting JVMs

Comment: Sorry but i do not have the benchmark tests... my question is based in the tomcat startup time, with jdk executable it takes 600.000 ms to start and with jre takes 160.000 ms. The difference is huge. the version is OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

Answer (score 10):

I'm late to the party, but... I came here looking for the difference between the several `java` variants within OpenJDK.  I only ended up with a few clarifications and additional questions to the "what's the difference between them" part of the question; hope it's helpful.

Looking inside the OpenJDK (I'm using OpenJDK 1.7.0) base directory I see *three* `java`s, all with different hash-sums:

- `bin/java`, binary
- `jre-abrt/bin/java`, binary; assuming ABRT is [Automatic Bug Reporting Tool](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-abrt.html)
- `jre/bin/java`, a shell script that `exec`s the `jre-abrt/bin/java` variant, in one of two different ways (more below).

The binary variants above have the same file-size and creation-time (in my version and system, anyway) but 4 bytes differ between the two files (I haven't looked much further -- this is the *other* part of your question -- but they *are* different, and it doesn't look like an ASCII string, for instance).

The script variant is the one you're saying is faster, which seems counterintuitive because it seems to be doing *more*.  (Or perhaps you're only seeing the time to execute the script and not the `exec`'d `java` command?).  The script checks to see if an ABRT shared-object file exists, and if so it passes (as `-agentpath...`) the `.so` and `abrt=on`.  Again, this seems like it should be nothing but *more* work... assuming use of ABRT.

If you're still interested in this topic, perhaps it would be interesting to see the following:

- what path in that script you're taking (check for existence of `/usr/lib64/libabrt-java-connector.so` or whatever is in your `jre/bin/java` script)
- if directly executing the third variant (`jre-abrt/bin/java`) is faster
- what else is being touched in both of these cases -- like `inotify` or `strace` or something, but this is probably enormous for a service like this.

Answer (score 4):

the java.exe files are actually the same. The JDK is the Java Development Kit, which includes all of the java executables you need to develop applications.

The JRE is the Java Runtime Environment, which includes what you need to run Java applications

So for running the application in a deployed mode, you would need only the JRE, as end users are likely to have only a JRE and not a JDK.

Comment: This does not address why the JDK version may be slower than the JRE... any ideas on that (the real) part of the question?